# deployment asp.net: No overload for method 'UpdateBookInfo' takes '5' arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I already published my client's site and I received problem during loading page.

Here's the error.

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'UpdateBookInfo' takes '5' arguments

Source Error:

```
Line 33:             //Update Book Info
Line 34:             Book BookProcess = new Book();
Line 35:             BookProcess.UpdateBookInfo(SKU, Title, Description, Price, Status);
Line 36: 
Line 37:             //Update Book Picture
```

Comment: what is the method signature? are you sure types of variables you passed are correct and matching?

Comment: yes, i'm sure of my variables. In my local its working

Comment: clearly you aren't passing the right number of arguments, and if it's working locally, it should be fine even when you deploy it, cross check the method signature !

Comment: make sure if you are updating the latest assembly to live deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the UpdateBookInfo() method signature - if you code is compiling locally then it should work after you deploy it. If you are using the publish from VS, make sure to change the version in AssemblyInfo.cs if the site is configured to precompile.

Comment: Can you take a snapshot of your bin directory in both server and you local environment and compare dll size and version? I am sure this is related to the new dlls are not getting copied to the server...